# getting 'the model backing context has changed since the database was created' even with migrations turned on

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use code first migrations in ef 6. I have enabled automatic migrations. There are no database initializers. There is an existing database. I have typed `Update-Database` in the console. There is only one context.

When I try to run the application, I still get the 'The model backing [context] has changed since the database was created' error. My understanding is that enabling migrations will prevent this error from happening without needing to set any database initializers.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Using `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>())` works, but I would like to know if there is a better way.